# Using backreferences for backreferencesing to a pattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre, backreference

Consider `(\w[0-9]).*\1` RegEx, it matches to `d1akdhfafd1`, `R2ddsfasfasfdsfdR2`, etc. .

Is is possible to write a RegEx that that match to following too: `D1dfsadfadsfE3`, `z6adfdasfdfr2`, `e3654654e0` ,....?

`\w[0-9]` is just an example, please consider general form `(::A_Complex_Pattern::).*\1`

Comment: You *might* mean recursion. http://php.net/regexp.reference.recursive - apart from that provide a PHP example with a subject string, your pattern, the actual outcome and the outcome you're looking for. It's not that clear what you ask about - a code example makes this always immediately clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's regex engine (PCRE) supports [recursion](https://www.php.net/regexp.reference.recursive). A few others do, but you generally shouldn't count on it. However, if the engine does, then you can insert patterns used elsewhere like this:

```
(\w\d).*(?1)
```

Where the numbering as the same as that for backreferences. `(?R)` would insert the whole pattern.

Comment: @Reza I was in fact wrong. I updated the answer with a solution to your problem.

Comment: Beside PCRE and related languages is there any other language that support recursion too? Is there any way to emulate this for use in JS?

Comment: @Reza according to wikipedia [only Boost does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#Language_features)