# PHP Use preg_replace for replacing space with &nbsp

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

How to use `preg_replace()` for change all space that is not within `<` `>` to `&nbsp`

```
$var="<  >< >Association football< ><  >"
```

to

```
$var="<  ><  >Association&nbspfootball<  ><  >"
```

What is the regular expresion for do this with `preg_replace()`?

Comment: Martin, please spend some time on Google researching your issues before coming to Stack Overflow.  You've asked a slew of back-to-back questions today that could have easily been answered yourself with a little research.

Comment: sorry but stackoverflow is a site for make questions,if you do not want to answer because you do not have to. I think it's a good question and I do not understand your criticism.Is a good question you should see the  response scores

Comment: if this '/ [] (? = [^ <>] * (: <| $)) /' is easy for you excuse me for being so inept

Comment: yes, @downvoter - would you care to leave a comment? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$var = preg_replace('/[ ](?=[^>]*(?:<|$))/', '&nbsp', $var);
```

---

See [**this efficiency demo**](http://ideone.com/NO8d7Q) to compare this solution with the one posted by [m.buettner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633117/m-buettner).

Comment: That is interesting. Do you have an idea why that is?

Comment: still the second one leads to generally much longer backtracking (unless - like it seems - PCRE is pretty clever)

Answer (score 4):

This is very similar to a [question just asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324569/using-backreferences-for-backreferencesing-to-a-pattern). Basically, you need to use a [lookahead](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php), to make sure that you can find either a `<` or the end of the string before the next `>`:

```
$var = preg_replace('/[ ](?=[^<>]*(?:<|$))/', '&nbsp', $var);
```

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/BN6xMG)

[Some more general information about lookarounds.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)